# MQTT Cloud - PHP - Web Server Publish Error

Tags: php, cloud, mqtt

does anyone know how to run this code because I enter all the information and variables correctly and it keep say timeout

```
<?php
require 'phpMQTT.php';

$url = parse_url(getenv('CLOUDMQTT_URL'));
$topic = substr($url['path'], 1);
$client_id = "phpMQTT-publisher";

$message = "Hello CloudMQTT!";

$mqtt = new Bluerhinos\phpMQTT($url['host'], $url['port'], $client_id);
if ($mqtt->connect(true, NULL, $url['user'], $url['pass'])) {
    $mqtt->publish($topic, $message, 0);
    echo "Published message: " . $message;
    $mqtt->close();
}else{
    echo "Fail or time out<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the format of your CLOUDMQTT_URL Environment variable?  That has all your connection info, and if it's not set right, you will get that error.  From the look of it, it should be in the form of "mqtt://mqtt_broker_ip:1883/my_topic"